# Setting up snowflake odbc on windows arm?

Tags: windows, arm, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use odbc snowflake to pull excel queries in windows arm. The only office (excel) that I can download is 32 bit. When I download the 32 bit snowflake odbc driver odbc 32 manager will not see it. I also noticed that when I open the 32 bit odbc manager it says 64 bit on the top. Naturally I tried downloading the 64 bit snowflake driver I can see it in the odbc manager but it won’t work. Anyone successfully set up odbc in windows arm?

Answer (score 0):

It definitely sounds like you are in the 64-bit Windows driver manager as least from the observations you noted.  I don't know ARM at all, but does the OS have a 32-bit Windows driver manager? Here is my location for it by default in Windows 10:

*C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\odbcad32.exe*

Comment: Yes. I’ve set it up many times on normal windows 10. If I pull up 32exe odbc driver it actual says 64bit on the top.

Comment: Okay, that's strange.  Can you make sure you run the whole path?  I'd had 64-bit one pop up before when just accessing the 32.exe directly or even just entered it in the search box.

Comment: Thx for the help Suzy. By following your folders it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To get to the `32 bit ODBC`, you have to run the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`. I've had the same issue. But still can't get the `Oracle 64 bit client` to work. Arm is turning into a nightmare for me.